# What should be done when one page has multiple parents?

Tags: url, breadcrumbs

I have a website which deals with mobile phones related information.

Now I have a webpage which has all articles related to a mobile phone. Now this page can potentially have two parents one being the "All articles page" and other being the "XYZ Mobile Phone Page". So which of the following breadcrumbs would suit more?

```
1. Mysite > All Articles > Articles Related to XYZ Mobile Phone
2. Mysite > XYZ Mobile Phone > Article Related to XYZ Mobile Phone
```

I am in a similar kind of dilemma when trying to decide the URL for this page.

Comment: What if you get off the hierarchy this webpage?

Comment: I would preferably want to keep it as a child of one of them in the breadcrumbs to give user a better site navigation overview.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use:

```
Mysite > All Articles > XYZ Mobile Phone > Article Related to XYZ Mobile Phone
```

Just to be completely clear about it.

Comment: But that would be wrong because _XYZ Mobile Phone Page_ isn't a child of the _All Articles Page_ and is not reachable via it. Just to be more clear _XYZ Mobile Phone Page_ has information specific to the phone which included related articles for it, whereas the _All Articles Page_ has the list of all articles in it.

Comment: If you plan to have so few articles that you do not want to categorize them then why bother making breadcrumbs? Just put a link to all articles on every page and be done with it. 

Your users don't know (or care) about the artificial distinction between articles and 'information specific to the phone' you've made. You must understand that the distinction you make as a developer between the two types of pages is completely arbitrary to a user.

Answer (score 1):

The thing to ask yourself when structuring a website is:  *How can my users find what they're looking for as quickly as possible?*

The question for breadcumbs is:  *How can I accomplish the above so users also know exactly where they are in my site, and how to find other relevant information in as few clicks as possible.*

With that in mind, something like this might help users find information related to specific mobile phones, while making it clear how to find information about other mobile phones in as few clicks as possible:

`Mysite > Mobile Phones > XYZ Mobile Phone`

The above is also more relevant to keywords like "Mobile Phones" and "XYZ Mobile Phone" (instead of "All Articles"), which adds relevancy to links as covered [here](http://moz.com/learn/seo/url).

If your directory and filename structure (i.e., URLs) also match your breadcumbs, then search engine users will see the same URL structure directly under your title in your SERP, making it clear where they are being sent to, where they are in your site, and in this example, that there's more mobile phone information just a few clicks away.

Comment: You are right but that is not what I asked in the question. Please have a look once again!

Comment: Are you asking for people to choose between your breadcumbs (1 and 2) as they are, verbatim?